# multiple matches in regex

Tags: javascript

Hi I am trying to get the following javascript code to work. When I am typing a line containing all three names
fever, nightsweats and nocturia - I want an alert window to come on reminding me that those three in combination represent a dangerous sign. what am I doing wrong? thanks so much in advance!!!

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_prompt() {
    var q = prompt("Please enter your name", "");

    var myRegExp1 = ^ ( ? = . * fever)( ? = . * night sweats)( ? = . * nocturia);
    var myRegExp2 = /fever,weight-loss,nocturia|weight-loss,fever,nocturia|nocturia,weight-loss,fever/
    var string1 = q;
    var string2 = q;
    var matchPos1 = string1.search(myRegExp1);
    var matchPos2 = string2.search(myRegExp2);
    if (matchPos1 != -1) {
        alert("bingo" + matchPos1);

    }
    if (matchPos2 != -1) {
        alert("symptoms" + matchPos2);
    }

}
</script>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="show_prompt()" value="Show prompt box" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What kind of input are you expecting/testing with?

Comment: Thank you for your help the correction worked beutifully. Now, suppose I use the following sentence as my input - "the patient, has been complaining of constant and dramatic weight-loss over the last month. recent hx: nocturia today at 4am, fever at 8am. what tags would I add to this? I've tried using /b and /y; neither one worked.

Comment: parsing natural language like that isn't going to be easy with a single regular expression... Also, what would you do if the text has something like, "but does not have a fever," in it?

Comment: perhaps add an if clause to the script that considers 3 scenarios where the hasn't appears in front of each the 3 variables? is there perhaps a source you can point me to

Comment: I would suggest making the input such that it is more easily parsable (i.e. not natural language).

Answer (score 0):

For one, you have a syntax error :

```
var myRegExp1 = ^ ( ? = . * fever)( ? = . * night sweats)( ? = . * nocturia);
```

Needs to be

```
var myRegExp1 = /^ ( ? = . * fever)( ? = . * night sweats)( ? = . * nocturia)/;
```

Comment: There's excess whitespace there, too.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I think this is what you want.  [**Please test it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/ruxma/)

```
function show_prompt() {
    var q = prompt("Please enter your name", "");

    var myRegExp = /(fever|weight-loss|nocturia),(fever|weight-loss|nocturia),(fever|weight-loss|nocturia)/;
    var string = q;
    var matchPos = string.search(myRegExp);
    if (matchPos != -1) {
        alert("symptoms" + matchPos);
    }
}
```